# Combining strings to a bound variable in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to include images in my Ember.js/Handlebars template.

I was using `<img {{bindAttr src="short_name"}}>` which would work if the image was exactly the value of short_name and in the root directory.

However, I need to construct the img src like this:

`'/images/avatars' + short_name + '_avatar.jpg'`

How would this be accomplished in ember/handlebars?

Comment: Where does short_name come from?

Answer (score 3):

Considering that short_name doesn't change, you could do it like this:

```
<img src="/images/avatars{{unbound short_name}}_avatar.jpg">
```

But if `short_name` change a lot, you should use a computed property like so:

```
var SomeModel = Ember.Object.extend({
  shortName: null,
  imgSrc: function() {
    var shortName = this.get('shortName');
    return '/images/avatars' + shortName + '_avatar.jpg';
  }.property('shortName')
});
```

And then on your template:

```
<img {{bindAttr src="imgSrc"}}>
```